(GAE) PHP Notice: ErrorException: Undefined variable $carry in /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:186
I am deploying my application to Google App Engine, Standard environment, PHP 8.3, Laravel v11.21.0
After its deploy, though, whenever I try to call any of its endpoints, it fails:
The request failed because the instance could not start successfully

and the only error message I can find in logs is the one in title:
PHP Notice: ErrorException: Undefined variable $carry in /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:186

I went and checked source files [1] [2] of this lib, and they seem OK in my opinion. Also I found no issues mentioning any of this.
<?php
// (...)
$carry = method_exists($pipe, $this->method)
                ? $pipe->{$this->method}(...$parameters)
                : $pipe(...$parameters);

return $this->handleCarry($carry); // line where it says $carry is undefined

Am I missing something, like a syntax error (unlikely, others would've opened issues by now)? Is there a possible scenario in which we go through these lines and $carry is not defined (even as null)?
Any help or tips would be appreciated. My other suspicion was that somehow the GAE is getting a different code than this of the lib (11.21.0), but I found no change or bug report around this method, and I couldn't find a way to download the deployed /vendor files. Also checked, the uploaded composer.lock does use laravel/framework as v11.21.0.
Full error in log:
PHP Notice: ErrorException: Undefined variable $carry in /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:186
Stack trace:
#0 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(256): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Undefined varia...', '/workspace/vend...', 186)
#1 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(186): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}(2, 'Undefined varia...', '/workspace/vend...', 186)
#2 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#3 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#5 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(110): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#6 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 /workspace/vendor/api-ecosystem-for-laravel/dingo-api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(109): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(145): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /workspace/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 {main}


Please update your question so that it includes a minimal repro of the issue. It's very difficult to help without this.

Hey, thanks for the comment @DazWilkin . What info would you consider essential for this to be reproducible?

An app.yaml and the minimal PHP code that uses Laravel that results in the error.
